# PDO select query with if/else statement doesn't work perfectly

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

Below is a script for a very basic search feature.

It works well, in the sense that the results do get fetched whenever it should but **the issue is that when the query should return zero result, `<div id="bar">No results!</div>` doesn't show up.** Instead the page is blank.

```
$search_query = $_GET['search'];
$search_query  = htmlentities($search_query);
$word = "%$search_query%"; 

$search=$sth->con->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE
firstname LIKE ? OR
lastname LIKE ?");

$search->bindValue(1, $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$search->bindValue(2, $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$search->execute();

    $results = $search->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $row) {
$firstname = $row["firstname"];
$lastname = $row["lastname"];

       if (!(count($results) == 0)) {  
?>

       <div id="foo">Here are your results</div>
<?php
        } else {

       <div id="bar">No results!</div>
<?php
        }
}
?>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `count` is in the wrong place. If there are no results, the `foreach` loop content never fires.

You want something like this:

```
<?php
if (count($results)) {
    echo '<div id="foo">Here are the results</div>';
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        // do stuff with row
    }
} else {
    echo '<div id="bar">No Results!</div>';
}
```

Or, since a non-empty array is "truthy":

```
<?php
if ($results) {
    echo '<div id="foo">Here are the results</div>';
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        // do stuff with row
    }
} else {
    echo '<div id="bar">No Results!</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no results, the `foreach` will never go into the body. You need to put the `if` around the `foreach`:

```
if (count($results) != 0) {
    ?> <div id="foo">Here are your results</div>
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ?> <div id="bar"> No results!</div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your `foreach` loop inside your first `if` block.  If there are no rows returned, your `foreach` has nothing to iterate over.

```
if (count($results))
{  

    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $lastname = $row["lastname"];

        echo '<div id="foo">Here are your results</div>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="bar">No results!</div>';
}
```

**Edit:**
I slightly altered your code so it wasn't going in and out of php blocks and a little easier to read.